# Why my SQL query does not work by Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I use his code for executing `SQL query` in entity framework :

```
using (var db = new VSServicesEntities())
            {                 
                const string selectCmd = @"if exists (Select top 1 IsUserOn From ServiceMembers Where ServiceCode={0} and Number={1}) 
                             Select isnull(IsUserOn,0) IsUserOn
                             From ServiceMembers Where ServiceCode={0} and Number={1}
                          else 
                             Select Null IsUserOn";
                 var data = db.ServiceMembers.SqlQuery(selectCmd, "A", 091242535970).ToList();
                if (data.Any())
                {

                   var serviceMember = data.First().IsUserOn;
                if (serviceMember.ToString() == "")
                    label1.Text = "";
                else
                    label1.Text = (serviceMember.ToString() == "True" ? "On" : "Off");
                }
    }
```

but it gives me an exception :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@ServiceCode".

but i give value to `ServiceCode= A` , what is the problem?

EDIT 2: I edited my query on top, but now it gives me another exception :

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'VSServicesModel.ServiceMember'. A member of the type, 'ServiceCode', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

but my column name is exactly : `ServiceCode`!! what is the problem??

Comment: Try by using "{0}" instead of "@ServiceCode", and "{1}" instead of "@Number", in your string

Comment: Take a look at the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679117%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing parameters correctly:

```
var data = db.ServiceMembers.SqlQuery(selectCmd, 
    new SqlParameter("@ServiceCode", "A"), 
    new SqlParameter("@Number", 091242535970)).ToList();
```

*Edit*

The type that EF will attempt to assign to `data` is the type of the element of `ServiceMembers` (assuming `ServiceMember`). The only field you return  is `IsON` which does not match the property `IsUserOn` which you reference. Try instead:

```
Select isnull(IsUserOn,0) AS IsUserON
...
Select Null AS IsUserON
```

Note that other properties will not be populated unless you return them from the query with matching names.

*Edit* You've changed your sql query - the binding was working correctly with `ServiceCode=@ServiceCode and Number=@Number`. At a guess, the reason why the `Reader` is complaining is because you are returning just one column (`IsUserON`) and trying to bind it to your full `ServiceMember` class. Either return all the columns (especially the primary key, presumably `ServiceCode`), or alternatively create a new class just with the property `IsUserON` and then use the generic type overload `db.SqlQuery<MyNewPoco>(cmd, ...)` to bind it.

Comment: it give me this error : The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'VSServicesModel.ServiceMember'. A member of the type, 'ServiceCode', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name. but the name of my column in sql server is exactly ServiceCode!!  what is the problem ??:(

Comment: I do it as you said, but it give me that exception